# Creating enum object in another class

Tags: java, enums

As a part of my coursework I am writing a basic game. The problem I'm having, I have a class called ship which stores all details about a ship, when a new ship is created I need to give it " in reserve " state. Then the user will be able to commission a ship and as a result its state will be changed to " active ".

I have an enum class called ShipState with the following code.

```
public enum ShipState implements Serializable
{
    RESERVE(" In reserves"), 
    ACTIVE(" Active"), RESTING(" Resting"), 
    SUNK ("      Sunk/Lost");

    private String state;

    private ShipState(String st)
    {
        state = st;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return state;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to create an enum object in my Ship class to give the ship state " in reserve ".

Comment: Why does the enum need to be in the other class instead of just importing and using the enum you provided?

Comment: It would help if you can provide the section of the ship class that needs to assign the ship state

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to 'create' an enum object. In fact, you can't. Instead, you reference the (`static final`) instances you declare in the enum:

```
//In Ship
public void setShipState(ShipState state) {
    this.state = state;
}

//In some manager class
public void putInReserve(Ship ship) {
    ship.setShipState(ShipState.RESERVE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I had similar solution earlier but it didn't work because when I tried to set the ShipState instead of doing ShipState.RESERVE I tried just writing RESERVE. Thanks once again.

Comment: You *could* just type `RESERVE`, `ACTIVE`, etc. if you typed `import static [package].ShipState.*;` at the top of the file, but that is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can have ShipState as a member in Ship and value can be set just by issussing ShipState.RESERVE.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Ship s1 = new Ship(ShipState.RESERVE);
}
public static class Ship{
    ShipState ss;
    public Ship(ShipState ss){
        this.ss = ss;
    }
}
```